# How to include a space and robot geometry with OMPL

Tags: quadcopter, rrt

Let us assume that I am able to create a 3D map (octree) based on information gathered by a Lidar and/or a camera on a quadrotor. Now based on the current 3D representation of the world, I want to go from the current pose to another one (which is in the known 3D environment).

To do so I want:

- First to create a set of waypoints by using rrt*;
- Then based on the waypoints, build polynomial curves.

So I took a look at OMPL, and although I understood the basics (well I think), I am still do not understand how to define the geometry of the robot (a box in my case) and how to define the working space (here a binary octree for instance).

From the examples I found, I see that goal and start spaces are defined, then a planner along with the problem definition is chosen, and finally solve. But I cannot see where the geometry and/or kinematics is defined no the world space...

Sorry for the naive question, but if somebody can provide a hint it will be very helpfull

Thank you

Comment: Actually I found one possibility, in case somebody will face the same situation. It is possible to use OMPL in conjunction with fcl (flexible collision library). Indeed fcl is able to read a binary octomap. So in the boolean function isStateValid (which is called by the ompl planner), you can test the collision using fcl.